# Can you identify the model of this Slot 1 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-detection

Can you identify the model of this Slot 1 motherboard?

It's been pulled from an old arcade cabinet from around 2000. It doesn't have any ports for keyboard, mouse etc. I cannot find any kind of identification online for it.

CPU: Intel Pentium II 450 MHz (80523PY450512PE). Video: AGP (I have 210-0364-003). The motherboard has a sticker on the ISA slot that states: BM-904VAT

[Slot 1 Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0dwO.jpg)

More Images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcW7q.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like BigBeam (korean, 1999), the model you found seems correct, BM-904VAT.
BIOS: http://www.elhvb.com/supportbios.info/Archives/BIOS/B-C/BIGBEAM/BM-904VAT/index.html
Would be very hard to find anything more I'm affraid.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Have you heard of BigBeam? I thought it might just be the brand of the BIOS chip and not the board. There is literally nothing on Google about this company! :[ I was hoping to find a compatible replacement board